# How to searialize an interface in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization

We have an object of class Asset. This Asset has an interface member EntityCollection of type `IList<AssetEntity>`. In a .asmx web service, we are serializing this Asset Object into XML and returning this XML.

But we are getting an error **"Cannot serialize member EntityCollection of type System.Collections.Generic.IList[AssetEntity]"**

Please help as to how to serialize.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the actual object type (that is implementing `IList<AssetEntity>` may not be a serializable type. The solution will be to implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface in Asset class and provide your own implementation for serializing to/from XML. As EntityCollection is a list of AssetEntity, serializing it as array of xml elements(nodes) should do the trick.

Here's a webcast about controlling xml serialization: http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/nuggets/nugget/96/Using-custom-serialization-with-ASMX-V20-Web-Services.aspx

This is another useful link in case you run into the trouble: forum where you may find answers related to xml serialization in asmx: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads/

Comment: We will try this solution and let you know.

Comment: The issue is that members of Asset themselves have further interfaces and they are there everywhere. What we finally chose is to write our own XML serialization for this object. +1 for assisting.

Answer (score 1):

XML serialization has some very picky rules about how collection-typed properties must be declared in order to serialize.  Notably, `IList<T>` fails because it does not extend the non-generic `ICollection`.

You may be able to get around this by exposing two properties: one public get-only `ICollection` for XML serialization to consume that is decorated with `[XmlElement]` and/or `[XmlArrayItem]` specifying the concrete element type(s) to expect within the collection, and one typed as you wish and decorated with `[XmlIgnore]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only de/serialize concrete types. These are the only types of instances that can exist in a program.

Comment: I think the problem is with the property/field, not with the item in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use plain array instead of ILIst, or just List.

Comment: Crude but undeniably effective.